# Unit Testing Front End Logic

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, agile, mvp

We have tried to introduce unit testing front end logic on a recent project and the value of the tests are being questioned.

We were not code reviewing the tests so the quality of them is poor, developers copied poor tests creating more poor tests and so we have a lot of crap tests.

I still believe there is value in testing the presenters (we use MVP) but getting people on board with this is more difficult than I originally thought.

How can I get people into thinking front end tests are valuable and has anyone got any good resources to point me to, to back me up with this?

Thanks...

Comment: Could you give us more information on why your tests are poor? What behavior are you "poor" tests actually testing?

Comment: Some of the tests aren't actually testing anything. What they should be testing are the following as well as any exceptional circumstances. [Initialise] – Are we making the correct number of calls to the service 

[PreSubmit] – Are we validating the object before submission and correctly handling errors 

[Submit] – Are we submitting the correct parameters to the correct service 

[PostSubmit] – Are we refreshing model correctly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unit testing front end logic is extremely hard since there are many parts that make it up like server side code changes to the front end and client side changes can all affect how the application appears.

On the Google testing [blog](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2009/08/tott-testing-gwt-without-gwttest.html) they talked about the value of testing all the parts of a MVP and the value of testing AJAX by stubbing the expensive parts [here](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/06/taming-beast-aka-how-to-test-ajax.html). Misko Hevery talks about the different tests [here](http://misko.hevery.com/2009/07/14/software-testing-categorization/) and I feel that the Front End tests fall into his large test category so always have the chance of false negatives/positives but they need to be sorted because they still offer a lot of value

Front end tests are extremely valuable as they check the user functionality hasn't dropped off. This is why tools like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org) and [Watir](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/) are so popular.

---

Comment: Tests with Selenium aren't unit tests though

Answer (score 4):

Fix the broken window. 
here is a link to the theory http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixing_Broken_Windows

A successful strategy for preventing poor code quality is to always keep your code base clean and in prestige condition. This means clean up all the bad code. It might be painful, and time consuming, but you will need to do it anyway.

After we removed all the compile warnings on our project, we found that our code quality has been improving. People start to care what they check in, since we send out a signal that it is not ok to checkin bad code(even warning is not ok), and no one wants to be the first one to break the window.

Answer (score 4):

Another pitfall when testing UI is that it is especially easy to end up writing tests that test the *framework* and not your application. Or said in reverse: it can be challenging to write test that actually test your UI and not the UI *framework*.

For instance, some teams end up writing lots of useless tests like:

```
Given a button, when the button is clicked, the event handler should fire.
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Our front end tests do ensure that an event gets hooked up and that the appropriate service calls are made.  Initially a lot of the framework had to be mocked in order for us to test the actual front end logic i.e. validation or service calls.  But once this was put into an abstract base class we could just test the appropriate logic.

Just as a matter of interest why do you find testing if an event is hooked up useless?

Comment: I'm saying that you don't want to test infrastructure that you didn't write. And if you did write the infrastructure, then write tests for it and don't test the infrastructure in your application tests. I use a 3rd party framework that assures me that their buttons fire events, so I don't test them. If you did write your UI framework, then write tests for it that test that buttons do fire their events. But then when you implement an app using buttons, don't test whether given button events fire, because the framework tests already assure you that buttons do fire events. Is that more clear?

Comment: It is clear, yes.  Our framework is engrained in the application using patterns such as the template pattern, so a lot of methods will get called in the Framework that tie back into our application methods i.e. On load framework calls XYZMethod witch in turn called X, Y, Z abstract methods in our application.  So our tests are doing something like OnLoadXCallsCorrectServiceTest().

Does that explain things any better?

Answer (score 1):

The question for me would be the trade-off between the costs of maintaining the tests and the probability of catching bugs that would not be caught otherwise. Presumably you will still have some visual testing of the actual UI (you'll do really well to test the aesthetics otherwise).

Can you for example focus only on some aspects of the Presenter. For example a non-trivial formatter, exercise that with lots of interesting values.

I suspect that one way to persuade is to proceed slowly. Try to find low-effort tests initially.